# ng-grid not Updating the data in the grid

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ng-grid

Initially the data is empty but later in the setPagingData() method it is getting updated. Checked the Data in console and $scope.Data is getting updated. But the data in the grid not getting updated. Any help..

```
class GridViewController {

   constructor( $scope,$timeout ) {
    $scope.gridView = {
          show : true
       };

  $scope.columnDefs = [
           {field : 'Id' , displayName : 'ID'},
           {field : 'name' , displayName : 'Name'}
        ];
  $scope.fData = [
      {
        "Id" : "123",
        "name": "John"
      }
  ]
  $scope.filterOptions = {
    filterText: "",
    useExternalFilter: true
  };
  $scope.totalServerItems = 0;
  $scope.Data = [];
  $scope.pagingOptions = {
    pageSizes: [250, 500, 1000],
    pageSize: 5,
    currentPage: 1
  };

  $scope.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize){
    var pagedData = data.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
    $scope.Data = angular.copy(pagedData);
    console.log($scope.Data);
    $scope.totalServerItems = data.length;
    if (!$scope.$$phase) {
        $scope.$apply();
    }
    $scope.$apply();
  };

  $scope.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page, searchText) {
    $timeout(function () {
        var data;
        if (searchText) {
            var ft = searchText.toLowerCase();
            data = $scope.fData.filter(function(item) {
                    return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(ft) != -1;
                });
            $scope.setPagingData(data,page,pageSize);
        } else {
              $scope.setPagingData($scope.fData,page,pageSize);
        }
    }, 100);
  };

  $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage);

  $scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal.currentPage !== oldVal.currentPage) {
      $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
    }
  }, true);
  $scope.$watch('filterOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
      $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
    }
  }, true);
  //console.log($scope.Data.length);
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data : 'Data',
    columnDefs : $scope.columnDefs,
    enablePaging: true,
    showFooter: true,
    totalServerItems: $scope.totalServerItems,
    pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
    filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions,
    rowHeight: 28,
    plugins: [new ngGridFlexibleHeightPlugin()]
   };
    gridViewScope = $scope;
  }
}
orderFlowApp.controller('GridViewController', GridViewController);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there seems to be a problem with ng-grid. Try something like this.

```
$scope.gridOptions.data = [];

$timeout(function () {
    $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.Data;
});
```